# Python Counting consecutive characters in a string

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, count, character

I'm working in a PSET6 for CS50 on edx, it's called DNA 
https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/6/dna/

And a video to explain the problem in details : https://youtu.be/j84b_EgntcQ

Here's the code down below that I need help with

I want to count how many times does the following set of characters repeats consecutively
"AGATC", "AATG", and "TATC"

which means if "AGATC" appeared one time , I ignore it, 
however if it's repeated back to back , so I count those, and so on , then return the maximum number was it counted

Here's a text for , you are free to edit for testing

that code , doesn't provide the needed results, because counter is grouping each letter
so is there's a way i can get the below result

```py
# code from https://www.journaldev.com/23666/python-string-find
def find_all_indexes(input_str, search_str):
    l1 = []
    length = len(input_str)
    index = 0
    while index < length:
        i = input_str.find(search_str, index)
        if i == -1:
            return l1
        l1.append(i)
        index = i + 1
    return l1

s = 'AAGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCATAGGTTAAAAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAATGAATGAATGTATCTATCTATCAGAAAATGAATGAATGAAGAGTATATCTATCAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG'

print(find_all_indexes(s, 'AGATC'))

# printed values: [3, 8, 13, 18, 39, 44, 49, 54, 59, 102, 107, 112, 117]
```

so now I'm able to find the location 
however i don't know how to count each consecutive ones

for example

locations 3 , 8 , 13 , 39, 44,54  are counted 6

then locations 102, 107, 112, 117 are counted 4

so the greatest number is 6

then I need to get this 6 please which is the maximum repeats this string was repeated

Comment: The point of the exercise is that you think of an algorithm which can do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code is based on your example, maybe you would need to optimize it:

```
import re

def find_all_indexes(input_str, search_str):
    max_count = 0
    for group in re.findall(f"(?:{search_str})+", input_str):
        count = len(re.findall(f"(?:{search_str})", group))
        if count > max_count:
            max_count = count
    return max_count

s = 'AAGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCATAGGTTAAAAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAATGAATGAATGTATCTATCTATCAGAAAATGAATGAATGAAGAGTATATCTATCAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG'

print(find_all_indexes(s, 'AGATC'))
```

Take a look again. You can check the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Comment: Hello dear , 
the result should look like this :-
AGATC_count = 1 , because it was repeated 1 time "4 words" ***********
AATG_count = 2 , because it was repeated 2 times "3 words each time" ***********
TATC_count = 3 , because it was repeated 3 times "3 words each time" ***********
I wish you find it clear for more support please :)

Comment: gotcha, checking again. It makes more sense now.

Comment: I updated the code for this answer, check if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: You are suppppper 
this is Very Good , it actually exactly what I need , 
I'll have to study your great code :)

Comment: Hello dear , 
It seems that I didn't understand the request correctly , Can you please check the amended question for help, 
apologize for the confusion

Comment: Please, take a look again. ;)

Comment: That's beyond perfect

Comment: would you mind suggesting a good source to learn python & algorithms
I'm new in this and really eager to learn

Comment: well, I did not apply any algorithms there, I just used regular expression (regex). I am going to check if I can find something for you.

Comment: many thanks for your support sir, and thank you in advance for your recommendations

Comment: Honestly, maybe you can wait for the topics to be investigated at the moment. But you can take a look of this course may be can help you https://www.coursera.org/specializations/python